# Request to API Flask-Restful with JWT header and JSON data

Tags: json, flask, request, jwt, restful-authentication

I'm trying to do the following from python:

This work:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET  -d "{\"Dato\":\"1\"}" http://localhost:5000/api/v1/recurso -H " Authorization: JWT ...p_GWs2XOAY"
```

My resource:

```
class RecursoPrivado(Resource):

@jwt_required()
def get(self):
    json_data = request.get_json(force=True)
    #data  = json.loads(json_data)
    return json_data

api.add_resource(RecursoPrivado, '/recurso')
```

I tried this, but return Response [401]

```
url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/recurso'
data={"Dato":"1"}
token="...p_GWs2XOAY" 
response=requests.get(url, data=data, headers={'Authorization':'JWT '+token})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `json=data` instead. Right now you're sending form-encoded data.

Comment: As an aside, it's somewhat non-standard to include a body with a `GET` request. Consider using a `POST` request instead.

Comment: That code should pretty much work, but you need to change `requests.post` to `requests.get`. (I imagine that tool got it wrong because it's non-standard to include a request body with a `GET` request.) But did you try my suggestion? That seems simpler.

Comment: For those who are confused, my previous comment was in response to a comment that has since been deleted. :-)

Comment: I regret to have deleted it, I published it more clearly

Comment: With json=data and GET Works!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! I added this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response = requests.get(url, data=data, headers={'Authorization': 'JWT '+token})
```

should be this:

```
response = requests.get(url, json=data, headers={'Authorization': 'JWT '+token})
```

You're currently sending form-encoded data rather than JSON-encoded data.